# Adding the same animation but in reverse, Css/Html

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm trying to find a way to add the same animation to a div element but in reverse. So that the animation will play on hover and once the mouse leaves the animation will play again but backwards. Thanks for any help in advance :)

You can find the code at: https://codepen.io/catheraaine/pen/LRVjdX

*PS: This is not my code I'm just using it for a project :)*

**Html:**

```
<div>
  <h1 class="sparkle u-hover--sparkle">
    Sparkle Hover
  </h1>
</div>
```

**Css:**

```
.sparkle:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.u-hover--sparkle {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

.u-hover--sparkle::before, .u-hover--sparkle::after {
  content: '';
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center;
          transform-origin: center;
}

.u-hover--sparkle::before {
  border-top: 0.1em solid #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 0.1em solid #ffffff;
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(0, 1, 1);
          transform: scale3d(0, 1, 1);
          transition-delay:0.3s;
}

.u-hover--sparkle::after {
  border-left: 0.1em solid #ffffff;
  border-right: 0.1em solid #ffffff;
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 0, 1);
          transform: scale3d(1, 0, 1);
          transition-delay:0.3s;
}

.u-hover--sparkle:hover::before, .u-hover--sparkle:hover::after {
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
          transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 900ms;
  transition: -webkit-transform 900ms;
  transition: transform 900ms;
  transition: transform 900ms, -webkit-transform 900ms;
  transition-delay:0.3s;
}
```

Again thanks for any help.

Comment: Transition is not the same as an animation

Comment: It was converted from .scss to .css so that's why that was probably changed from animation to transition. Could that be the case?

Comment: Nope... `transition` is not the same as `animation`. The later requires `@keyframes`

Answer (score 0):

when making animations, for them to play when you hover and when you leave your mouse, you need to put the default values of the element

```
.sparkle {
  max-width: 10em;
  color: $c-text;
  margin: auto auto;
  &:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  &::before,
  &::after{
    transform: scale3d(0,0,0);
    transition: transform 900ms;
  }
}
```